# (Unity 2D, C#) How to detect when a raycast STOPS hitting a hitbox, cast from inside of it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to make an AI in a 2D racing game that can complete *any* course you can throw at it. Soon a level maker will be created. However, I need to give the AI some senses. To see, I'm trying to give it a few raycasts in many directions, which will give it a rough overview of where walls are. However, to make your own levels, it'd be a lot easier to make a level hitbox instead of wall hitboxes. PolygonCollider2D in Unity can make a good hitbox of almost any simple image with transparency I can throw at it. I'm saying this because that's an alternate solution. If anyone knows how to make some kind of hole in a screen-wide hitbox automatically based on an image, like the inverse of PolygonCollider2D, that'd also help.

Anyways, how it's set up now is there's an automatically generated level hitbox, and whenever the car goes off, it explodes.

However, because I need it to be the other way around, things related to raycasts don't seem to work properly. Here's the code I'm using so far to make these raycasts (Just one in the forward direction).

```
    public void Sight()
    {
        RaycastHit2D forward = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up), 10f);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up) * 10f, Color.red);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up) * forward.distance, Color.green);
    }
```

See, it works fine...only when I cheat to go OUTSIDE the stage. Then, it easily detects when the raycast hits the stage's hitbox. Inside, it thinks the distance is zero, since it IS inside the hitbox.

I've tried using "forward.point", which supposedly tells me the X and Y coordinate of the impact point, but that didn't work. It just worked outside the stage, not from the inside. I tried making a universal hitbox, however, I don't know how to make the stage "nullify" the background hitbox. Essentially it made no difference to the raycast whether it was on or off the track. I also don't know how to get the position of the end of the ray, maybe then I could make a sensor from the outside in?

Last thing, the first solution that came up on StackOverflow didn't work. It seemed like it would, but it did the same solution, because the "void" hitbox was literally everywhere. If I knew how to make an INVERSE hitbox using the stage's auto generated one, or a way to ignore the stage only when the raycast is touching it or something, then it'd work. But what I tried from it, it didn't.

Comment: would you not test under the wheels of the car for track? if track ok else cheat? or Ala F1 allow 1 side off sort of, but not both?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if I explained it correctly. The collision itself is just fine. it works perfectly. My issue is I need to make some kind of way to detect HOW FAR each of these walls are from the car. I'm trying to cast a line from the car, which extends until it hits a wall in front of it. However, raycasting assumes you are outside of a hitbox and trying to hit it. Mine is being cast from the inside and I need to be able to detect where that stops.

Comment: Why not just reverse your colliders?  Make the non-track graphics the collider.  Then your script will work as is.

Comment: Well, do you know how to do that? At some point the User will be able to draw their own track, and I don't know how to "cut holes" in the hitbox (but I do know how to generate a hitbox based on that track). Do you know any way I can invert the hitboxes generated from that?

Also I tried making a big background collider that envelops the whole screen, but the problem was when i did that there was no difference whether the raycast was on or off the track, it always registered as hit. So if you know how to make one hitbox nullify the other, that'd be great too.

Comment: Update: I tried making an image of all the negative space with the track removed, that would be stupidly hard to actually implement, but even then, it did not work. It just generated a screen sized square. So yeah, I am essentially stuck with a stage hitbox, not wall hitboxes. The only choice I have is to either make a raycast that works from within that hitbox, or have some kind of way to make that stage hitbox nullify a screen-wide kill zone (including to the raycast)

Comment: Some pictures of one of your tracks would improve this question considerably. Could you add those? I don't think what you're asking is particularly possible in the Unity engine. An alternate solution would be to programmatically convert the walls of your hitboxes into 2d wall colliders. So your users would just be able to draw the collider as you said they could, and then your game converts those into colliders just at the edges of your track, allowing raycasts to hit them.